# Adding a link on an email that was executed by a PHP code

Tags: php, html, email

I have this form to mail code where users will receive and email from the form that was submitted.

Here's the whole code:

```js
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once ('database.php');

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

$reqname = $_POST['reqname'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$empname = $_POST['empname'];
$position = ($_POST['position']);
$account = $_POST['account'];
$platform = $_POST['platform'];
$processor = $_POST['processor'];
$ram = $_POST['ram'];
$monitor = $_POST['monitor'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$phonetype = $_POST['phonetype'];
$headset = $_POST['headset'];

{
$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO request (reqname, day, month, year, empname, position, account, platform, processor, ram, monitor, phone, phonetype, headset)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$insert = $database->prepare($insert_query);
$insert->execute(array($reqname, $day, $month, $year, $empname, $position, $account, $platform, $processor, $ram, $monitor, $phone, $phonetype, $headset));

$email_from = "PC Request";//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "PC Request for $account";
$email_body = "Here are the specifications:\n\n".
  "Requested by: $reqname\n".
  "Start Date: $month/$day/$year\n".
  "Employee Name: $empname\n".
  "Position: $position\n".
  "Account: $account\n".
  "Platform: $platform\n".
  "Processor: $processor\n".
  "RAM: $ram\n".
  "Monitor: $monitor\n".
  "Phone: $phone\n".
  "Phone Type: $phonetype\n".
  "Headset: $headset\n".
        "Link: $link\n".
    
$to = "email@email.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$link = "www.google.com" \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body, $headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
//header('Location: index.php');

echo "<script>alert('Successfully sent!'); window.location='index.php'</script>";
}
}
?>
```

So is it possible to add like a link on the email body?

As you can see I've tried creating a variable named link then declaring it to the email body, but obviously it didnt work.

New Edited Code:

```js
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once ('database.php');

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

$reqname = $_POST['reqname'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$empname = $_POST['empname'];
$position = ($_POST['position']);
$account = $_POST['account'];
$platform = $_POST['platform'];
$processor = $_POST['processor'];
$ram = $_POST['ram'];
$monitor = $_POST['monitor'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$phonetype = $_POST['phonetype'];
$headset = $_POST['headset'];

{
$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO request (reqname, day, month, year, empname, position, account, platform, processor, ram, monitor, phone, phonetype, headset)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$insert = $database->prepare($insert_query);
$insert->execute(array($reqname, $day, $month, $year, $empname, $position, $account, $platform, $processor, $ram, $monitor, $phone, $phonetype, $headset));

$email_from = "PC Request";//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "PC Request for $account";
$email_body = "Here are the specifications:\n\n".
  "Requested by: $reqname\n".
  "Start Date: $month/$day/$year\n".
  "Employee Name: $empname\n".
  "Position: $position\n".
  "Account: $account\n".
  "Platform: $platform\n".
  "Processor: $processor\n".
  "RAM: $ram\n".
  "Monitor: $monitor\n".
  "Phone: $phone\n".
  "Phone Type: $phonetype\n".
  "Headset: $headset\n".
  <a href='https://google.com'>Google</a>
    
$to = "email@email.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body, $headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
//header('Location: index.php');

echo "<script>alert('Successfully sent!'); window.location='index.php'</script>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You created the variable *after* you tried to use it.  You also created a syntax error, so this won't execute at all and you'll see an error in your PHP logs...

Comment: `\r\n` needs to be inside the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use HTML to create your link:

```
<a href='https://google.com'>Google</a>
```

and put it in the body of your mail

And make sure you put the correct content-type in your headers:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;";
```

Comment: But that code is the body of the mail.

Comment: You need to put `Content-type: text/html` in the headers, and make the rest of the message valid HTML.

Comment: @Barmar Hmm where do I put the `Content-type: text/html`?

Comment: You put it in `$headers`.

Comment: Try googling how to send html email from php.

Comment: @Barmar Should I do this? $headers = "Content-type: text/html"; lol

Comment: @WadeBoar append it to $headers, don't overwrite the headers

Comment: @Laurens Hi, please check my new edited code if it's correct

Comment: You need to make the message body valid HTML. Use `<br>` for line breaks, not `\n`. Otherwise it will show everything on the same line.